# How to make a cross platform Library?

Tags: c++, libraries

I was trying to make a HTTP server using sys/socket.h on Linux. I am wondering that how can I make a cross platform HTTP server without using 3rd party libraries. I just want use the native socket API'S. How can I compile a library that loads the specific header according to the underlying operating system. Like loading windows.h on windows and sys/system.h on Linux.

Comment: You can look at how Boost Asio does it and learn from there.

Comment: Don't spam tags please!

Comment: What you are looking for is called conditional compilation.  If you google that you'll get plenty of references of how that works.

Comment: *native socket API'S* and  *cross-platform* are two contradicting requirements.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Not really - there are two meanings to "cross-platform". The reasonable one is a library with a cross-platform API and platform-specific implementations. E.g. Boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'traditional' method is to use `#ifdef` macros, with which you can select which h-file to include at compile-time, like so:

```
#ifdef LINUX
    #include <sys/platform.h>
#else
    #include <windows.h>
#endif
```

Then you can let the compiler define the right macro using the `-D` option, such as `-DLINUX`.

But that will land you in a lot of pain when the API's start to differ ever-so-slightly.

Use the [boost](https://www.boost.org/) libraries! These are designed to be platform-independent.

Comment: The question is *I just want use the native socket API'S. How can I compile a library that loads the specific header according to the underlying operating system.*.  This does not answer that.

Comment: It does now. I thought that was clear from the start.